# Hot questions are too wide in landscape mode

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, hot-questions, ios-app

I just noticed that the iOS app works in landscape. Which is quite nice. The hot questions, though, appear to not know how to resize themselves.

Take for example this screenshot:

[image]

The first item in the second row could do with being made less wide - that little green "a" way over on the right side looks kinda weird.

Comment: BTW, awesome job on the app. It's amazing.